# Footage of SHG in smoke/fog

Tags: laser, education, non-linear-optics

I am looking for a footage of second harmonic generation performed with laser and a non-linear crystal in which infrared light is converted to visible light. But I also want that to be performed in smoke or fog so that the laser beam is "visible" (or rather visualized). Such setup would be a very good demonstration of the phenomenon of the frequency doubling. Sadly, I only found the footage of the demonstration without the smoke, but in such setup the SHG doesn't look different from simple light scattering on the crystal.

Can you provide me with any links to the footage as described above, that undoubtedly demonstrates the frequency doubling?

Answer (score 0):

The only visible colour in most DPSS lasers is 532nm (green). The pump is 808nm, and the gain medium lases at 1064nm -- both of these are infrared and invisible to the eye. So you wouldn't see much by smoking out the cavity.

Here's a great illustration though: https://www.repairfaq.org/sam/dpss1asm.gif

Comment: If we would put fog in the setup on the illustration, wouldn't we see a beam of green 532 nm light coming out of the Nd:YVO4 crystal, with no visible beam coming into the crystal?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that you wouldn't see anything exciting like colour changes. Just green light being produced.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be produced "out of nothing"? I mean, you don't see the beam of infrared light going to the crystal, but on the other side the green light comes out as if created out of thin air by the crystal. I think it would look quite exciting.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I think it's cool too, just not as dramatic as a colour change :)